# CoreLocation CLLocationManagerDelegate returns cached/delayed locations in mid-flight

Tags: ios, ipad, core-location, cllocationmanager

Is there a possibility for CLLocationManagerDelegate method [locationManager:didUpdateLocations:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager?language=objc) to return cached values in middle of usage?

Or is there a known bug for CoreLocation not working well with hight-speeds or high-altitudes?

I have airplane tracking application, and some users using older iPad devices, are notifying me, that application is showing their position incorrectly (around 3-4min delay). I have also text log implemented, and it shows correct timestamps without delay.

Application renders views and logs data as soon as it get's new location, and no queueing is possible so it shouldn't be a problem.

Can CoreLocations throttle so bad (CPU issues?) to fire up delegate with such huge delay? Can speed be a reason for it? As i said it is used on small planes, so speed is much bigger than in cars.

Edit: To be clear, im checking for actual timestamps, and always getting last element of array from didUpdateLocations

Comment: May be below can help you out. i am not sure by the way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111459/ios-core-location-get-most-accurate-location-coordinates

Comment: you may also check for verticalAccuracy property in locationManager instance.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Thank You for link! The problem is: Data i receive is correct, and has good accuracy. So this resolution won't do anything. Only problem is with latency: I get them with 3-4 minutes delay. And for verticalAccuracy: i check both vertical Accuracy and horizontalAccuracy and dismiss location if they are incorrect.

Comment: then it may be due to following similar scenario 
https://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works
it first go to satellite ... and vice versa.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem. Im afraid i described it poorly. Is the issue understandable?

Comment: no it explains why your data is late when you are in airplane data goes to satellite , satellite transmit to you and so on i have  answered  that is exactly your problem.

Comment: @Mabeh You mention older iPad devices, do you know if these devices are GPS enabled? remember that Wi-Fi only iPads do not have a built-in GPS, which means the OS would have to get the location from Wi-Fi.

Comment: @quant24 Hey, most affected devices are mini2 with cellular. They do have GPS, cause they work well... Untill they suddenly cease. I found similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551494/background-location-service-stops-working-in-a-period-of-time But for me, its when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and help from apple support (big help) it looks that cause was changes in ios12.

Had to set activityType for .otherNavigation prior ios12 and .airborne for ios12+

Previously this option didn't seem to had any impact...

Answer (score 1):

You can't get real-time data without an operational need, and organizations which do receive real-time data cannot legally re-distribute this data publicly, except to other organizations approved by the FAA. An operational need pretty much means you have to be a flight dispatcher for an airline or commercial operator, not just have an interest in tracking flights. For more details 
Check following
[check here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-an-api-to-get-real-time-faa-flight-data)